# Github Actions: Push docker image build by gradle task

Tags: docker, github, github-actions, docker-push

For building images of my current project, I use the gradle task `bootBuildImage`. This task creates a [OCI image using Cloud Native Buildpacks](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#build-image).

```
- name: Build image with Gradle
  run: ./gradlew bootBuildImage
```

With the next step I'm trying to push this docker image to my private GitHub registry using [build-push-action](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action).

```
- name: Push image to Registry
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v1
  with:
    username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
    password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
    registry: docker.pkg.github.com
    repository: sullrich84/wettkampfdb-backend
    tags: latest
  env:
    DOCKER_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
    DOCKER_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
```

As I can tell from the logs, the problem with this step is that it seems to rely on a `Dockerfile` located in the workspaces root directory which does not exist.

```
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: 
  lstat /github/workspace/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

Is it possible to push the image created via `bootBuildImage` to my private GitHub registry without using/creating a dedicated `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 3):

If you are just looking for something to deal with `docker push`, you can just use the native `docker` command to do it.

Something like this.

```
      - name: run docker push
        run: |
          @docker login -u $DOCKER_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD
          @docker push $BUILD_TAG
          @docker push $LATEST_TAG          
        env: 
          DOCKER_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          DOCKER_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
```

Answer (score 2):

The github-action you are using is not for pushing an image you define by `repository` and `tag` but rahter `build and push` https://github.com/docker/build-push-action#build-push-action

> Builds and pushes Docker images and will log in to a Docker registry if required.

Specifically this is also related to https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/issues/17 - so just building without pushing is possible, not vice versa.

This github action does yet not allow just pushing.

This is for now very common for a lot of CI/CD solutions, where build and push are one task.

Answer (score 1):

I use publishRegistry option of gradle bootBuildImage.
Set parameter in your build.gradle (below is gradle.kts)

```
tasks.bootBuildImage {
    imageName = "${imageName}:${project.version}"
    isPublish = true
    docker {
        publishRegistry {
            url = dockerUrl
            username = dockerUsername
            password = dockerPassword
        }
    }
}
```

check this [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.0/gradle-plugin/api/org/springframework/boot/gradle/tasks/bundling/BootBuildImage.html)

Comment: The current option to publish is actually `publish` instead of `isPublish`, see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.customization